# How to trigger a mousemove event when mousedown in C# Form

Tags: c#, user-controls

I build an UserControl in C# form.
And I use MouseMove event in the event list.
Everything works properly.

Then,I want to detect if right or left button of mouse is pressed.
The MouseEventArgs provide Button status to use.

The issue is when left button on mouse is already pressed somewhere outside the UserControl ,then move the cursor on to the UserControl,MouseMove event just won't trigger.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean if someone is doing a mouse drag over the `Control` in question? Look into the mouse drag events.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've try the DragDrop and DragEnter event.
It won't trigger either.
There is no object to drag into my UserControl.

Comment: --And I need the coordinate in MouseEventArgs for my application.

Comment: This is because the MouseDown has happended somewhere else and therefor the MouseMove of that other place still keeps happening. This is a good thing so you don't lose the event just because you happen to slip aside, eg from a scrollbar.

Comment: You can capture Mouse coords anywhere on screen with a lowlevel mouse hook.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `MouseDown` has happened somewhere else and therefore the `MouseMove` of that other place still keeps happening.

This is a good thing so you don't lose the event just because you happen to slip aside, eg from a scrollbar.

If you really want to prevent the good thing happening at that special place you can release the mouse capture that is going on..:

```
private void theOtherPlace_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (! theOtherPlace.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        User32_DLL.ReleaseCapture();
    }
}
```

Using this helper class:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
..
public static class User32_DLL
{
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
}
```

Not sure if it is a good idea, though! I for one am always very happy if I can rely on the pressed mousebutton to still work the way it should..

Or you could trigger the `MouseMove` of the `UserControl` from the other `MouseMove`, passing in the UC as sender and a modified `MouseEventArgs`:

```
private void theOtherPlace_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (! theOtherPlace.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        Point pt = yourUserControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        if (yourUserControl.ClientRectangle.Contains(pt))
        {
            yourUserControl_MouseMove(listView1, 
                            new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, pt.X, pt.Y, e.Delta ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see ! Thanks for the guidance.I'll keep trying.I'm new to Stackoverflow. If  I offend anything, please let me know. Thank you again!

Comment: Nothing wrong with your question; in fact it is rare for a newbie to  upvotes on his 1st question!  Do have a look into the [voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) system, which drives the site to a considerable extent!